# Image grid layout with web component images

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, web-component, shadow-dom

My goal is to achieve this layout for an array of Images:

[image]

As you can see, a simple 2 column grid of square images - this is quite easy in a Bootstrap environment where one specifies 2 cols or size 6 each, then simply setting the images' CSS `object-fit` to cover in order to avoid stretching and setting the height to auto.

Problem is, where I'm trying to achieve this is in Ionic 4 where the img element is a web component and only certain properties are exposed to that can be customized. So far I can get the images displayed in a 2 column fashion but the aspect ratios are off.(Also I HAVE to use the  element, so cannot simply use HTML5 img element).

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let image of selectedImageURIs">
                <ion-img [src]="image"></ion-img>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```

Note: The Ionic Framework has it's own 'Bootstrap' like framework called ion-grid. What I end up with is this:

[image]

I know need to get them to be the same in height and with and set the object fit to cover, but how can I do this with an ion-img? I is a web component so the Shadow Dom comes into play. The docs just mention `"The component uses Intersection Observer internally"`. Will that be able to do what I need? I'm new to web components to trying to understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I used for my Ionic 4 app. I used css to accomplish the look you're going for. Your template will look something like this and using `ion-img` to take advantage of the lazy loading feature.

`html`

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let category of categories" size="6">
      <button #categoryButton type="button" (click)="selectCategory(categoryButton, category)" class="category-button">
        <ion-card padding class="category-card">
          <ion-card-content class="category-card-content">
            <ion-img *ngIf="!imageNotLoaded; else loadingCategory" src="{{category.icon_image}}" class="category-icon" (ionError)="imageNotLoaded = true"></ion-img>
            <ng-template #loadingCategory>
              <ion-skeleton-text animated style="height: 70px;width: 70px"></ion-skeleton-text>
            </ng-template>
          </ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title class="category-title">{{category.name}}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Set up your sass code like this.

`scss`

```
ion-col {
  text-align: center;
}

.active {
  .category-card {
    border-color: var(--ion-color-primary)!important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 16px var(--ion-color-primary)!important;
  }
}

.category-button {
  padding: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  .category-card {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid;
    .category-card-content {
      text-align: center;
      .category-icon {
        width: available;
      }
    }
    .category-title {
      font-size: x-small;
      font-weight: bolder;
    }
  }
}
```

This then yields the final result as this picture below.

**Note:** this is all component level code other wise you'll need to use `::ng-deep` to get around the shadow dom for your css code.

[image: grid display using ion-grid and ion-img]

Answer (score 0):

page.html

```
<ion-row class="row-card">
  <ion-col size="6" class="col-card">
    <ion-card class="card-service">
      <img src="../../assets/images/services/w-medical.png" class="img-service" />
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="6" class="col-card">
    <ion-card class="card-service">
      <img src="../../assets/images/services/w-professional.png" class="img-service" />
    </ion-card>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

page.css

```
.row-card{
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;

    .col-card{
        padding: 0px;

        .card-service{
            margin: 5px;
            height: 160px;
            border-radius: 0px;
            padding: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px;

            .img-service{
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border: 0 solid #024f9a;
                background: linear-gradient(#0486ca,#024f9a);
                border-radius: 50%;
                padding: 15px;
                font-weight: bold;
                }    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image][Here is working one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-2vk3tf?file=pages/home/home.html)

```
ion-grid >
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-3 *ngFor="let image of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]">
        <img src=''/>
          <!-- <div class="image-container" [style.background-image]="'url(assets/img/' + image + '.jpg)'"></div> -->
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
```